# Limit involving fractional part function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, number-theory, asymptotics

> I need to prove that the limit in [this bountied question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744325/a-question-on-beta-function/4746210#4746210) $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n\ 4^{2n}}{e^{2n}}\{d_{2n}b_n\}\leq \frac{3}{4}$$ where $d_{2n}=\text{LCM}(1,2,...,2n)$ and $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. It is known by the above link that $$b_n:= -\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj^2(2(H_{n-j}-H_j)\ln((j+n)!)$$

I would really appreciate an answer which I can accept. Thank you!

Comment: What motivates this problem? Could you give us some context?

Comment: @Gary Thanks for your comment. I was just thinking about this problem. Nothing particular other than the link given in the question. Mathematica gives that after some $N$ we have the $$\frac{n\ 4^{2n}}{e^{2n}} \left\{e^{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\left(\log \left( {\frac{{3n}}{2}} \right) +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)\right)\right\}\to 0  $$

Comment: Shouldn’t $a_n$ contain $\binom{2n}n\gamma$ or a $\sum\limits_{j=0}^n \binom n  j^2 H_{j+n}$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Please see the question linked in this post. $a_n$ is the sequence as defined in the linked post and $$b_n=-a_n= -\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj^2(2(H_{n-j}-H_j)\ln((j+n)!) $$ and by the link in this post Gary proved that as $n\to \infty$ $$b_n=-a_n=\binom{2n}{n}\left(\log \left( {\frac{{3n}}{2}} \right) +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)\right) $$

Comment: Using the $O(1/n)$ formulation won't be productive, because it's being multiplied by $e^{2n}$ (and then some) which completely scrambles the values of the fractional part.

Comment: @GregMartin Then can we just use the asymptotic with the $O(1/n)$ part? Can the another representation of $b_n$ be used? I request you to write as an answer.