# Asymptotic equality of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, asymptotics, laplace-method

> I need an asymptotic equality for the integral $$\int_{(0,1)^5} \left(\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)u(1-u)v(1-v)w(1-w)}{1-(1-xyuv)w}\right)^n \frac{dxdydudvdw}{1-(1-xyuv)w} $$ where $$\int_{(0,1)^5}=\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1$$

Define  $$I_n:=\int_{(0,1)^5}  \left(\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)u(1-u)v(1-v)w(1-w)}{1-(1-xyuv)w}\right)^n \frac{dxdydudvdw}{1-(1-xyuv)w} $$
I tried using [Laplace's method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) and so we use the substitution $x_1=2x-1,y_1=2y-1,u_1=2u-1,v_1=2v-1,w_1=2w-1$ to get
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2^{5n}}\int_{(-1,1)^5}  \left(\frac{(1-x_1^2)(1-y_1^2)(1-u_1^2)(1-v_1^2)(1-w_1^2)}{2^5-(2^4-(x_1+1)(y_1+1)(u_1+1)(v_1+1))(w_1+1) }\right)^n \frac{dx_1dy_1du_1dv_1dw_1}{2^5-(2^4-(x_1+1)(y_1+1)(u_1+1)(v_1+1))(w_1+1))} $$
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit $1$** Can we use the result from p.$331$ in this book [Asymptotic expansions of integrals](https://zlibrary-asia.se/book/2324920/7e96e1)? I don't know how to apply this result in our question.

**Edit $2$** $I_n$ can be written as $$I_n=\int_{(0,1)^5} \exp\{n\phi(x,y,u,v,w)\}g_0(x,y,u,v,w)\ dxdydudvdw$$ where $$\phi(x,y,u,v,w)= \log\left(\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)u(1-u)v(1-v)w(1-w)}{1-(1-xyuv)w}\right)$$ and $$g_0(x,y,u,v,w)=\frac{1}{1-(1-xyuv)w}$$ So $I_n$ is an integral of Laplace's type.

Comment: This probably looks like part of attempt to prove irrationality of $\zeta(5)$ along the lines of Beukers's proof for irrationality of $\zeta(2),\zeta(3)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Sorry, but just knowing the asymptotic, can we say anything about the irrationality of $\zeta(5)$?

Comment: Beukers used estimates for 2d and 3d integrals of similar fashion to prove the irrationality of $\zeta(2),\zeta(3)$. I have discussed his approach in my blog posts https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/10/irrationality-of-zeta-2-and-zeta-3-part-1.html?m=0 and https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/10/irrationality-of-zeta-2-and-zeta-3-part-2.html?m=0

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks a lot. But how do prove that there exists integers $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$, $D_n$ such that $$I_n=\frac{A_n\zeta(5)+B_n\zeta(4)+C_n\zeta(3)+D_n}{d_n^5}$$ where $d_n=\text{lcm}(1,2,...,n)$. Is there a formula for $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$ and $D_n$?